# Is $f: \mathbb{Z}_m \longmapsto \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ given by $f\left(\left[x\right]_m\right)=\left[nx\right]_{mn}$ an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $f: \mathbb{Z}_m \longmapsto \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ given by $f\left(\left[x\right]_m\right)=\left[nx\right]_{mn}$ an isomorphism when $n \geqslant 2$?

The only thing that is missing in my proof is surjectivity. I think, that $f$ is not surjective and not isomorphic, though. I always have troubles proving or disproving surjectivity formally. Any help is appreciated.

$\left[u\right]_m$ denotes the class of the integer $u$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Comment: Isomorphic groups have the same number of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two groups are isomorphic only if they have the same cardinality. In this case you have $|\mathbb{Z}_m|=m$ and $|\mathbb{Z}_{mn}|=mn$; hence, since $n \geq 2$ by hypothesis, those two groups are not isomorphic.